# How to run scikit's cross validation with several classifiers on the same folds

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I'm currently working on a research study about classifiers performances comparison. To evaluate those performances, I'm computing the accuracy, the area under curve and the squared error for each classifier on all the datasets I have. Besides I need to perform tuning parameters for some of the classifiers in order to select the best parameters in terms of accuracy, so a validation test is required (I chose 20% of the dataset).

I was told that, in order to make this comparison even more meaningful, the cross validation should be performed on the same sets for each classifier.

So basically, is there a way to use the **cross_val_score** method so that it runs always on the same folds for all the classifiers or should I rewrite from scratch some code that can do this job ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The cv is by default StratifiedKFold for classification with shuffle=False. So you should get reproducible folds.

Answer (score 1):

[cross_val_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html) accepts a `cv` parameter which represents the cross validation object you want to use. You probably want [StratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html), which accepts a `shuffle` parameter, which specifies if you want to shuffle the data prior to running cross validation on it.

`cv` can also be an int, in which case a `StratifiedKFold` or `KFold` object will be created automatically with `K = cv`.

As you can tell from the documentation, `shuffle` is `False` by default, so by default it will already be performed on the same folds for all of your classifiers.

You can test it by running it twice on the same classifier to make sure (you should get the exact same results).

You can specify it yourself like this:

```
your_cv = StratifiedKFold(your_y, n_folds=10, shuffle=True) # or shuffle=False
cross_val_score(your_estimator, your_X, y=your_y, cv=your_cv)
```